# Why doesn't YouTube cache videos?

Tags: youtube, cache

Normally, if we watch a video (or view an image), it's stored in the cache (local disk). But YouTube doesn't cache videos. As far as I know, they use the cache but it's temporary. As soon as browser tab is closed, the cache is gone.

Both they and we can save a lot of bandwidth by using cache technology properly. So, why aren't they using it? What are they trying to achieve by not using a cache?

Comment: Only YouTube can answer. All we can do is speculate.